# Spliting a single column into two different columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have something like this:

```
Column  
  1  
  2  
  3  
  4  
 -1  
 -2  
 -3  
 -4
```

And I wanted an output something like this:

```
C1  C2  
1   -1  
2   -2  
3   -3  
4   -4
```

Can anyone help me on writing a query to get this output in T-SQL??

and what if something is like this:

```
 values  
   1  
  -5  
  10  
  -9  
  15  
  -3  
   8  
 -11  
  12  
 -17
```

and I have to make two columns that separates the positive values in one column and negative values in another.

Comment: You can do a self-join on the table, however I think you need to be more specific about what you want. How should C1 relate to C2?

Comment: Positive and negatives count values are equals? Is there the same negative value for each positive value?

Comment: If all you're doing is joining positive values with the corresponding negative values, then do a (full? left? inner?) self-join with `ABS()` or `0 - ...`. This isn't hard. What have you tried?

Comment: do you want all negative values in C2?

Comment: I updated my answer to match your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182627/spliting-a-single-column-into-two-different-columns-sql-server/49182710#49182710

Comment: If this is SQL Server, why do I see `plsql` tag there????  Tag properly!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select max(col1), min(col1)
from t
group by abs(col1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.. a simple self-join

```
create table test1
(
   col1 int not null
)


insert into test1 (col1) values (1)
insert into test1 (col1) values (2)
insert into test1 (col1) values (3)
insert into test1 (col1) values (4)
insert into test1 (col1) values (-1)
insert into test1 (col1) values (-2)
insert into test1 (col1) values (-3)
insert into test1 (col1) values (-4)

select a.col1 C1, b.col1 C2 from test1 a 
join test1 b on a.col1 = -b.col1
where a.col1 > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `JOIN` the table with itself and then limit the result so the negative ones are excluded from the first column

```
SELECT t1.Col1 c1, t2.Col1 c2 FROM tbl t1
JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1*-1 AND t1.Col1 > 0
```

**Answer to second question:**

The idea is to SELECT positive and negative numbers separately and then do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on their row numbers.

```
SELECT t1.Col1 c1, t2.Col1 c2 FROM (
    SELECT t11.Col1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t11.Col1 ASC) rn
    FROM tbl t11
    WHERE t11.Col1 > 0
) t1 FULL JOIN (
    SELECT t22.Col1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t22.Col1 DESC) rn
    FROM tbl t22
    WHERE t22.Col1 < 0
) t2 ON t2.rn = t1.rn;
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( Col1 int );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (6), (7), (-4), (1), (-2), (3), (5);

-- RESULT
| c1 |     c2 |
|----|--------|
|  1 |     -2 |
|  3 |     -4 |
|  5 | (null) |
|  6 | (null) |
|  7 | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT t1.col1 as C1,
>        t2.col1 AS C2
> FROM   tbl t1
> JOIN   tbl t2
> ON     t1.col1 = (t2.col1 * -1)
> WHERE  t1.col1 > 0
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> C1 | C2
> -: | -:
>  1 | -1
>  2 | -2
>  3 | -3
>  4 | -4
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7ad1e01edd825bbf16b1dc5a7155791)*

Comment: Thanks!!.. it worked for me by this logic.

Comment: Now what i will do in the second secnario..??

Answer (score 0):

You can join the values of the two queries by using the analytic function ROW_NUMBER():

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1 desc) AS row_num
      FROM TABLE_1
     WHERE col1 < 0),
     B AS (
    SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS row_num
      FROM TABLE_1
     WHERE col1 >= 0)
SELECT A.col1 AS C1, B.col1 AS C2
  FROM A
 INNER JOIN B
    ON A.row_num = B.row_num;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex Zen this logic worked..